# Google Cloud Storage Client App error using Go Runtime Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Im trying the example code from [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) and trying to do operations on 
Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Storage Client App from Go runtime , But the following part in the sample code is giving the error ***"cannot use c (type "appengine".Context) as type context.Context in function argument:*** ***"appengine".Context does not implement context.Context (missing Deadline method)"***

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
hc := &http.Client{
    Transport: &oauth2.Transport{
        Source: google.AppEngineTokenSource(c, storage.ScopeFullControl),
        Base:   &urlfetch.Transport{Context: c},
    },
}
```

Whats the issue here ?? How can i solve this ??

Answer (score 5):

The error message clearly states that you try to pass a value of type `appengine.Context` where the expected type is `context.Context`.

The [`google.AppEngineTokenSource()`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#AppEngineTokenSource) function expects a value of type [`context.Context`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context#Context) and not the one you pass (which is of type `appengine.Context`).

You can create such `Context` with the function:

[`cloud.NewContext(projID string, c *http.Client)`](http://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud#NewContext)

This is how I would do it:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
hc := &http.Client{}
ctx := cloud.NewContext(appengine.AppID(c), hc)
hc.Transport = &oauth2.Transport{
    Source: google.AppEngineTokenSource(ctx, storage.ScopeFullControl),
    Base:   &urlfetch.Transport{Context: c},
}
```

Comment: Yes, i understood the log message , but couldnt figure out a call to obtain context.Context . Sad that the example code published doesnt work  like it is claimed on the page . @icza Can you please suggest an edit to the`handler` function in the link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted to fix my issue . Im not able to use the suggested function with right formulation of  parameters to get it working .

Comment: @KarthicRao Edited the code with how to fix it. Please check if it works.

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you it worked :) u made my day :) Google should update the page  , otherwise its a great inconvenience to everyone who is using it !

Comment: the code is compiling good but the im getting the log as `Demo Failed' .I just ran the write and read operation , they are not working , the write is not able to write into the bucket and obviously read no table to fetch it later

Comment: here is the error on the `createFile` function ..... `createFile: unable to write data to bucket "xxxx-87609.appspot.com", file "demo-testfile-go": Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/xxxx-xxxx-87609.appspot.com/o?alt=json&projection=full&uploadType=multipart: not an App Engine context`

Comment: I have opened an issue on Google Cloud Platform Repo ,https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/issues/118  , please contribute when possible

Answer (score 2):

You need to update from `appengine` to `google.golang.org/appengine` as described there: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/#app-engine